From listing 1. to 1. listing in \autoref of a lstlisting
I'm using listings to display code in my document, and all is okay, or I was able to find a solution, except for one problem. When I autoref a listing, it references as "listing 1." in the text, but I would rather have it as "1. listing".
Can someone help me out? I've been looking everywhere and didn't find anything.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

I suspect that you need this for documents in Hungarian. I think \autoref is unusable in Hungarian because of the conjugation! However, here is a possible solution to change the order.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch,listings,hyperref}

\def\lstlistingautorefname{listing}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\HyRef@autosetref}{\HyRef@currentHtag}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\HyRef@autosetref}{\null}{\null.~\HyRef@currentHtag}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\HyRef@testreftype}{~}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Example},label={listing:example}]
  code
\end{lstlisting}

\autoref{listing:example}

\end{document}



The answer of hair-splitter is great, I found an other method, which was easier to understand for me, and works like a charm, with all types of autoref-ed content:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{lstlisting}{source code}{source codes}  
\Crefname{lstlisting}{source code}{source codes}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}  
\Crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}  
\Crefname{table}{table}{tables}
\crefname{section}{title}{titles}  
\Crefname{section}{title}{titles}


\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\ref*{#1}. \nameCref{#1}}} ```


In this case the \autoref* does not work.

Thank you for your comment, @hair-splitter , might be true, haven't used \autoref* as it is required that the numbers are shown where referencing basically anything in my document.
